# How can I execute 1TB log file python script in command line

Tags: python, sys

I have a log file which consists the capacity of 1TB. I am uncertain that how to run this python script in the command line. I use the sys library but still my csv data is not added.

Below is my python code.

```
import re
import sys
from csv import writer
import datetime
log_file = '/Users/kiya/Desktop/mysql/ipscan/ip.txt'
output_file = '/Users/kiya/Desktop/mysql/ipscan/output.csv'

try:
    ip_file =sys.argv[1]
except Exception:
    print("usage: pythone3 {} [ip file]".format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit()

name_to_check = 'MBX_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED'

with open(log_file,encoding="utf-8") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if name_to_check in line:
            username = re.search(r'(?<=userName=)(.*)(?=,)', line)
            username = username.group()

            ip = re.search(r'(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])',line)
            ip = ip.group()

            with open(output_file, 'a') as outfile:
                outfile.write('{username},{ip}\n'.format(username=username, ip=ip))
```

Comment: What is the point of the `ip_file` variable?  You never use it.

Comment: Do you get output from `print (date)` and `print (time)`?

Comment: @JohnGordon I only get 1 date and time in csv, not the whole date and time

Comment: Not in the csv file, I mean the `print()` statements which would just print to the screen.

Comment: @JohnGordon in print(), it does not show the output, it shows like this usage: pythone3 /Users/kiya/PycharmProjects/implace/pythonpractice.py [ip file]

Comment: If you're not seeing output from the `print()` statements, then that must mean `MBX_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` is not in any lines in the input file, therefore no output is ever written.

Comment: If I run this script without sys library, it executes very well in Pycharm, but I am not sure how to run this code in command line

Comment: When you run the script from the command line, it requires a filename argument after the script name, even though it doesn't use it for anything.

Comment: Missing a [mcve] as well as problem description. Voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it work well and if the problem persist check your search regex :

```
from sys import argv

log_file = ""
if len(argv) > 0 :
    log_file = argv[1]
else :
    quit("No log_file specified, exiting script.")

with open(log_file, encoding="utf-8") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if name_to_check in line:

            username = re.search(r'(?<=userName=)(.*)(?=,)', line)
            username = username.group()

            date = re.search(r'(?P<date>\d{8})\s+(?P<time>\d{9})\+(?P<zone>\d{4})', line)
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date.group('date'), "%Y%m%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            print(date)

            time = re.search(r'(?P<date>\d{8})\s+(?P<time>\d{9})\+(?P<zone>\d{4})', line)
            time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time.group('time'), "%H%M%S%f").strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            print(time)

            ip = re.search(r'(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])',line)

            with open(output_file, "ab", buffering=0) as outfile:
                outfile.write( ("{},{},{},{}\n".format(username, date, time, ip)).encode() )
```

Comment: is this the code to run using the command line?
the reason is because everyday I am receiving lot of file, so it would be inconvenient if I edit the code every time for different file and it is more convenient to run it like
python3 example.py file.txt

Comment: ~@KatarinaAlves see the modification, if it didnt work give me some lines of log_file and I will give you the right regex to extract data, nice day